# user Cellular request failed

Tags: ios, request, afnetworking

I use `AFHTTPSessionManage` to POST a request in iOS.

This works with a wireless connection but not with a cellular connection.

```
 AFHTTPSessionManager*task = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
[task POST:URL parameters:nil progress:^(NSProgress * _Nonnull uploadProgress) {

    NSLog(@"%f",uploadProgress.fractionCompleted);

} success:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nonnull task, id  _Nullable responseObject) {

    NSLog(@"%@",responseObject);

} failure:^(NSURLSessionDataTask * _Nullable task, NSError * _Nonnull error) {
    NSLog(@"%@",error);

}];
```

Comment: in wifi no problem,but in cellular network not

Comment: Cannot access server,just request timeout! before i update AFNotworking , its okay in cellular and in wifi, need i set some property?